# What gem and mana are sacrificed when I play seal of exile?

Tags: mythgard

When I play seal of exile in Mythgard, what gem and mana are sacrificed? Do I keep unused mana and gems or are they sacrificed in priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you play seal of exile, the gem you used to cast it (or orange gems you used earlier in your turn) are sacrificed.

If you managed to somehow reduce seal of exile's mana cost to 0, it wouldn't make you lose 1 mana because the sacrificed mana is maximum mana (which determines how much mana you get at the start of your turn) and not actual mana.